# Chrome FileSystem API maximum number of files in directory

Tags: google-chrome, html5-filesystem

I'm working with the Chrome FileSystem API and I keep running into an issue with the number of files in a directory. It looks like there's a limit of 100 files per directory. Unfortunately I can't find any confirmation of this and was wondering anyone else has encounterd this or can confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=378883

You have to keep using readEntries until the response is empty